# Get procedure name at run time in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a stored procedure in teradata.
I would like to capture activities within it at run time.
Is there a way i can get the procedure name while it is being executed.
I can then use the procedure name and the message while logging.

I am trying to avoid hard coding of the procedure name.

Can you please let me know if there are any parameters in teradata that support this or any other suggestions ?

Thanks !